# why var++ in swift is wrong but change to var+1 is right

Tags: ios, swift, macos

[image]

new to learn swift, why the first is wrong? 
thx~~ ˊ_>ˋ

Comment: The cause is very simple: you need to add a blank between the operator and the closing curly brace and remove the space between currentAudioIndex and operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `currentAudioIndex++` (without space) . It's same as : `currentAudioIndex = (currentAudioIndex)%2`

```
currentAudioIndex = (currentAudioIndex++)%2 
// plus 1 to currentAudioIndex will be overrided by `currentAudioIndex =`.
// With (currentAudioIndex++)%2. E.g currentAudioIndex = 1
// 1. currentAudioIndex return 1 for the operator %. It's "1%2"
// 2. currentAudioIndex plus 1. currentAudioIndex == 2 now.
// 3. The operator % (1%2) return 1 for currentAudioIndex.
// 4. currentAudioIndex == 1  at the end.
```

But in your case, I think you want this `++currentAudioIndex`.It's same as

```
currentAudioIndex = currentAudioIndex + 1
currentAudioIndex = (currentAudioIndex)%2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just know that I should click the check to mark the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

currentAudioIndex++ increments the value after the expression is evaluated.
You can try ++currentAudioIndex to increment before the expression is evaluated.